# Put typeface to textview in android dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android. I have a textview and want to assign custom font to it. My font file (*.ttf) is on the server. I have to use that file in code to set font dynamically (on the fly). I don't want to put the file in asset folder or any raw folder. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download font from server
2. Save to SD card
3. Use [Typeface.createFromFile(String path)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromFile%28java.lang.String%29)
4. `textView.setTypeface(yourTypeface);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your font file to asset folder and then use this in your java code.

> Typeface temp = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/RadioLand.ttf");
>
> ```
>   bat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
>     bat.setTypeface(temp);
> ```