# Is it possible to use fonts hosted in remote server in react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to custom fonts in my application. For android, I can use fonts when I include .ttf or .otf file under assets folder. But what if I want to use fonts hosted in remote server. Is it possible to use these fonts?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, you need to define fonts in your plist file, which is in a read-only location on your phone by the time your app is running. So, unless there's a clever hack I'm not aware of this is not possible.

Looks like it is possible in Android, so it's likely to be possible in React Native as well. See [Put typeface to textview in android dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969102/put-typeface-to-textview-in-android-dynamically)